# Unity C# XML How to load a saved position and a saved stage

Tags: unity, c#, savegame

I have a problem. I already figured out how to save the player stats (including the player position). But every time I load it back, the player ends up in the saved position but still within the open scene, not the saved scene. Nothing else got passed, no errors. Nothing happened except for the player ending up in the saved position, yet still within the open scene, not the saved scene. Here is the code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    
    public class ReadWrite : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string path;
        public PauseScreen ps;
        public SaveData activeSave;
        public bool hasLoaded;
        public PlayerController ball;
        
        void Start()
        {
            hasLoaded = false;
            ps = FindObjectOfType<PauseScreen>();
            ball = FindObjectOfType<PlayerController>();
        }
    
        public void SaveGame()
        {
            string dataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Save.txt";
            activeSave.unitName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
            SpawnPointChoice.SetSpawnPoint(activeSave.unitName);
            activeSave.score = ScoreSystem.score;
            activeSave.lives = LivesSystem.lives;
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveData));
            var stream = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Create);
            serializer.Serialize(stream, activeSave);
            stream.Close();
            Debug.Log("Your game has been saved.");
            ps.Resume();
        }
    
        public void LoadGame()
        {
            string dataPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Save.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(dataPath))
            {
                Debug.LogError("FILE NOT FOUND");
            }
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveData));
            var stream = new FileStream(dataPath, FileMode.Open);
            activeSave = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as SaveData;
            stream.Close();
            ball.transform.position = activeSave.transformPosition;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(activeSave.unitName);
            ScoreSystem.score = activeSave.score;
            LivesSystem.lives = activeSave.lives;
            Debug.Log("Your game has been loaded");
            hasLoaded = true;
            ps.Resume();
        }
    }
    
    [Serializable]
    public class SaveData
    {
        public Vector2 transformPosition;
        public int score;
        public int lives;
        public Scene unit;
        public string unitName;
    }
```

The line where I have a comment saying "Load saved scene" is where I need assistance. Any would be appreciated.

Edit: Now, right after the game was successfully loaded, it reloaded the start of the game.

Sincerely,
Jay Burch

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130881/discussion-on-question-by-jay-burch-unity-c-xml-saved-files-only-turn-out-to-be).

Answer (score 1):

`SceneManager.LoadScene("")` tries to load a scene with an empty name, which is not going to work. You likely intend to do `SceneManager.LoadScene(activeSave.unit.name)`, which is the variable where you saved the name of the current scene to.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work. Came up with an error, which was what I was afraid of. Cannot load scene: Invalid scene name (empty string) and invalid build index -1

Comment: Sounds like your save file was lacking a saved scene name, or the scene name didn't correctly get deserialized into your `activeSave` variable. Try debug logging the value of `activeSave.unit.name`. You might also want to consider making `activeSave.unit` a plain string variable, and saving just the name into it.